# Clarification on Reduced Row Echelon form and Echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Pardon me for asking this basic question, but I needed clarification in the definition of Row reduced echelon and Echelon form. From what I know, a matrix is in Echelon form if:

- Any row consisting of entirely zeroes must be at the bottom of the matrix.
- For each row that does not contain entirely zeroes, the first non-zero element is one which is called the pivot/leading element/.
- For $2$ successive non-zero rows. the leading one in the higher row must be on to further right of the leading one in the lower row.

and it's called reduced row echelon with the following additional property.

- The leading $1$ in every row contains zeroes below and above in that particular column.

According to the foresaid definition, the below matrix should not be Echelon:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

However, our professor insists that since the matrix is equivalent to the identity matrix, it also must be a Reduced row Echelon matrix. I wanted to confirm if this is correct since I did not find any supporting argument anywhere on the internet and it contradicts my previous understanding of this topic.

Comment: On the third point: it should be on the further left rather than right. And that matrix is certainly neither in ref nor in rref by any definition of these

Comment: Thankyou very much for the clarification sir.

Comment: By being "equivalent" your professor means "row equivalent".  This is a shortcut for saying it can be row reduced to the identical matrix.  
At some point, after defining "invertible" matrices, you will run into the property, "Every invertible matrix is row equivalent to the identity matrix."

Comment: Clarification:  Row equivalent does not mean equal.

Comment: Okay i got it, Thankyou everyone for your valuable replies!